# Integrate $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+\cos(mx)} \cos(\rho \sin(x)) dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

In one of my problems, I encountered the integral:
$$\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+\cos(mx)} \cos(\rho \sin(x)) dx$$
where $\rho$ and $m$ are parameters. 
I would be satisfied if the answer was given for $m=1$, and if the square root would be expanded using the Taylor series.

Naturally, I have already tried all of this and checked it in Wolfram Alpha. But it said there was no answer. I am also definitely not interested in numeric integration

Comment: **Welcome to the site !**. May I ask you a question ? Where did you catch this monster ? Even with $m=\rho=1$ would be very difficult (not to say more).

Comment: For $m=1$, I have something with Bessel functions.

Comment: Be sure that I never thought about a Taylor expansion. Just the infinite series from binomail theorem. I shall mak a few numerical checks tomorrow.

Comment: Some stuff has been added to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote, the idea is to develop the square root using the binomial them.

So, for $m=1$, we face integrals
$$I_n=\int_0^\pi \cos ^n(x) \cos (\rho  \sin (x))\,dx$$

Using a CAS
$$I_n=\sqrt{\pi }\, 2^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \left(1+(-1)^n\right) \rho ^{-n/2} \,\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) J_{\frac{n}{2}}(\rho )$$ provided $\rho \in \mathbb{R}\land \Re(n)>-1$.

This means
$$\color{blue}{I_{2n}=\sqrt{\pi }\, \left(\frac 2 \rho\right)^n\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) J_n(\rho )}$$
and $I_{2n+1}=0$.

So, for
$$K=\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+\cos(x)} \cos(\rho \sin(x))\, dx$$

$$\color{red}{K=\sqrt{\pi }\,\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{2 n} \, \left(\frac 2 \rho\right)^n\, \Gamma \left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right) J_n(\rho )}$$ which will probably converge very slowly since, for large values of $n$ ($a_n$ being the summand), for any $\rho$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\left(16 n^2-1\right) J_{n+1}(\rho )}{8 (n+1)\, \rho \,  J_n(\rho )}=1-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{137}{48 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
Computing the sums up to $p$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
p & \rho=\frac 12& \rho= 1& \rho= 2 \\
 100 & 2.644596475 & 2.122507198 & 0.4988469627 \\
 200 & 2.643719191 & 2.121631131 & 0.4979757517 \\
 300 & 2.643425787 & 2.121337955 & 0.4976834850 \\
 400 & 2.643278902 & 2.121191150 & 0.4975369993 \\
 500 & 2.643190713 & 2.121102998 & 0.4974489948 \\
 600 & 2.643131895 & 2.121044200 & 0.4973902779 \\
 700 & 2.643089870 & 2.121002188 & 0.4973483140 \\
 800 & 2.643058345 & 2.120970671 & 0.4973168285 \\
 900 & 2.643033822 & 2.120946153 & 0.4972923322 \\
 1000 & 2.643014201 & 2.120926535 & 0.4972727305 \\
 \cdots     & \cdots            &  \cdots           & \cdots \\            \infty &2.642837512 &2.120749860 & 0.4970961248
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Looking at the numbers given in the table, we could notice that the difference between the summations up to $100$ and up to $\infty$ are almost constants (respectively $0.00175896$, $0.00175734$ and $0.00175084$).

So, we could *approximate* the infinite summation writing
$$K=\sqrt{\pi }\,\sum _{n=0}^{p } \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{2 n} \, \left(\frac 2 \rho\right)^n\, \Gamma \left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right) J_n(\rho )+$$ $$\sum _{n=p+1}^{\infty }\sqrt{\pi }\, \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{2 n} \, \left(\frac 2 \rho\right)^n\, \Gamma \left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right) J_n(\rho )$$ and, as already done for the ratio test, use for large orders
$$J_n(\rho) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n} }\left(\frac{e\rho}{2n}\right)^n $$ which makes for the second summation
$$\sum _{n=p+1}^{\infty }\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum _{n=p+1}^{\infty }e^n n^{-(n+\frac{1}{2})} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{2 n} \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Using composition of Taylor expansions to $O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ we have 
$$\sum _{n=p+1}^{\infty }\sqrt{\pi }\, \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{2 n} \, \left(\frac 2 \rho\right)^n\, \Gamma \left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right) J_n(\rho )\sim \frac{\psi ^{(1)}(p+1)}{4 \sqrt{2}}$$ which, for $p=100$ gives $\approx 0.00175896$ (!!)

Comment: This problem appeared in a Physics problem I am having. I was actually reluctant to use the Taylor expansion because it has to include the derivative of what is inside the square root, but your suggestion about using the binomial term and the other expressions you wrote were very helpful!